# Error : Allowed memory size x of y bytes exhausted Cuando en realidad aun queda memoria

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy teniendo este error en laravel (php 7.1) cuando intento renderizar 5000 rows en una tabla.

Me confunde el tema porque el servidor tiene permitido elocar 500MBs de memoria, pero explotó al intentar usar 6MB.

Toda la app esta en laravel bajo centos 7.0 y php 7.1, el servidor web es litespeed y el panel es CPANEL.

#### Error:

> ```
> #message: "Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3853532 bytes)"   #code: 1   #file:
> "/home3/otecdoctum/otec/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Readers/HtmlReader.php"
> #line: 183   #severity: 0
> ```

Comment: Listo, se ha traducido a ambos idiomas.

Comment: No te olvides del titulo ;)

Comment: prueba registrando en el log los parámetros que ve la app `Log::info('[debug] - U:' . ini_get('upload_max_filesize') . ' P:' . ini_get('post_max_size') . ' T:' . ini_get('max_execution_time') . ' M:' . ini_get('memory_limit'));`. esto se guarda en `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: donde has configurado eso 500Mb de memoria en cual php.ini?

Comment: Gracias por contestar.
Los 500mb estan  configurados tanto en el php.ini usado por apache como el de litespeed, adicional a eso de forma local hay un php.ini y allí tambien lo setie.